# In what situations do you use the .future property?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

When should I use the .future property in Riverpod's FutureProvider?

Conversely, when should I not use the .future property?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `.future` property will return... a Future. This Future can be awaited using the `await` keyword in an async block. The resolution of the Future will **not** rebuild the provider if you watch it with `ref.watch(yourFutureProvider.future)`.

If you don't use `.future` with your FutureProvider, an `AsyncValue<T>` will be returned. If you use `ref.watch()` on your provider, the calling provider/widget will be rebuilt every time the state of the `AsyncValue` changes (`AsyncLoading`, `AsyncData`, `AsyncError`).

`AsyncValue` make it easy for the UI to react to the different states of your provider, as you can use the `.when()` method on it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When do you actively use the .future property?

Comment: Usually inside other providers, when no UI is involved. When I don't do anything special during the `await` time of my Future.